# Python3 OpenCV on Raspberry Pi Zero: VideoCapture for USB cam on /dev/video0 returns always False but camera works correctly if I access it via motion

Tags: python, opencv, camera, raspberry-pi-zero

I try to use OpenCV in Python 3 on a Raspberry Pi Zero to capture a video frame from a USB camera identified as `/dev/video0`. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
...
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if cam.isOpened():
    print("Camera successfully opened")
else:
    print("Camera could not be opened")

while True:
    success, image = cam.read() 
    print("success in taking image? ", success)
    if success and not image.empty():
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        // further code to be excecuted to process the image
    else:
        print("problem capturing image")
```

The output is

```
Camera successfully opened
success in taking image? False
problem capturing image
success in taking image? False
problem capturing image
success in taking image? False
problem capturing image
...
```

It will never take an image successfully. It worked once (`success = True`) for a single iteration the very first time I executed my script but since then it is not working any more. So my first assumption was that the camera is broken. But if I use motion to access the camera, it works flawlessly. So the camera is connected correctly.

Any clue on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Should be `if success:` instead `if success and not image.empty():`

Comment: what is "motion"? can you access the device with just ffmpeg or guvcview? list the programs that work and those that do not. -- figure out what modes (frame size and rate and pixel format/compression) this camera supports. ffmpeg can help you list those.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz ffmpeg says
`[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x1a58e40] Compressed:       mjpeg :          Motion-JPEG : 1280x720 640x480 320x240 320x180 800x600 848x480 640x360 1280x800
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x1a58e40] Raw       :     yuyv422 :           YUYV 4:2:2 : 1280x720 640x480 320x240 320x180 800x600 848x480 640x360 1280x800`

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz and yes, with ffmpeg it works. I can record video from the camera. Motion is another tool for video recording and with that one it works as well. So the cam is ok, it just does not work with OpenCV in Python 

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz got it solved - see answer below. Stupid fault of mine. Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: that is why we always insist on a [mre]. nobody could have guessed that. you ran code you didn't show, and the code you did show is the code you didn't run. please also step through your code before posting next time. this is vital and prevents you from wasting not just your own time on this.

Comment: completely understood and usually I also do this. But the code is huge and it would have been difficult to extract that specific point. Sorry and thank you. Also I have to say that the answer below (marked as an AI answer) actually helped me to solve the problem as I stepped through all the possible solution options and when I came to point 5., I realized that `cam.release()` could be the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got the problem solved. It was a concurrency issue. I had put a `cam.release()` in a `finally:` block but in the wrong one so always right before I was trying to take a picture accidentally this `finally:` block was excecuted and the cam was released **BEFORE** actually trying to take a picture